# How to step through 3D noise for volume textures?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, fragment-shader

I'm creating volume textures for volumetric ray marching (Creating this with Unity and a fragment shader)
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2wgT.png)

I have depth value that increases the starting position on the x, y or z axis.
Doing this additivley, results in an ulgy side view where you can see the stacked planes.
Example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEy83.png)

When I multiply the depth value with the starting position, the result is a bit more convincing but the frequency will increase with the depth. I didn't find any 3D noise algorithms that take an extra parameter for the frequency, they all do it with the UVs (the position in my case).
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P07iZ.png)

Can't really figure out how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
As I was stepping along the z-value of the noise, I was **multiplying** it by my depth value. This of course increases/decreases the frequency.
**All I had to do was to add** it to the z-value.